# Play framework apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache, ssl, playframework-2.0, reverse-proxy

This is my first question in SOF.

I am trying to set up reverse proxy using apache for a web server ruing java Play(https://testhost:20443).

I got the following configuration in the httpd.conf and it works for the most of the pages

```
ProxyPass       /t/  https://testhost:20443/
ProxyPassReverse /t/  https://testhost:20443/
```

The user see the URL as

```
"https://localhost/t/xxxx" instead of "https://testhost:20443/xxxx".
```

---

But I have the following route define in Play

```
    # Home page
    GET     /                          controllers.Application.login()
    POST    /session                   controllers.Application.authenticate()
    GET    /session                    controllers.Application.redirect(url="/"

)
```

When the application goes to `"https://testhost/session"` it reverse back to "https://localhost/session" instead of `"https://localhost/t/session"`.

Any help , idea is really appreciated. Thx